# How to convert a bin image to an iso image?

Tags: macos, iso-image

I ask this question on superuser, not stack overflow because it is not exactly a programming question.

I am on Mac OS X and i want to convert my .bin image generated by my NASM compiler program into a .iso image readable by VMWare Fusion or Virtualbox!
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The bin program you created, is actually the first part of an executable.  Under MS-DOS, you would use something like exe2bin.

There are bin files, that are created by some cdrom readers, that come with a matching cue file, you would search for bin2iso, and convert that way.  Under windows, isobuster and alcohol120 will convert these.